# Grok debuger log tomcat local.access in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok

I have a random tomcat log file with the following content
`10.0.30.23 [22/Aug/2023:00:00:30 +0700] "GET /zkau?dtid=z_qe0&cmd_0=rmDesktop&opt_0=i HTTP/1.0" 200 17 0`

please help me solve it how to parse it

I'am tried parse in the the Grub debuger, Kibana but Provided Grok patterns do not match data in the input